# Hot code swap in Android Studio with libgdx

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, libgdx, hotswap

I am using Android Studio (IntelliJ) to program Android apps and am facing a problem with hot code swapping and libgdx. 
When I run the desktop application in demo mode everything works fine. If I try to change a bit (e.g. the color of an element) nothing is refreshed in the application. Even if I select Run->Reload changed changes a new gradle build is started (takes very long) and then says couldn't find any changes.

I have imported the same sample application in eclipse. There I can just change something in the code and it is immediately shown in the running app.

Anyone else experiencing this issue? Why is this not possible in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, hot swap debugging does not appear to work when using the Gradle template.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible as specified [here](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=20859), you need to disable the *Android Support* plugin if you want hot code swap to work with Gradle and libGDX.